# eclipse not working on mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

I think it is something to do with java.

Its for my android app class, eclipse can't find the path or do any of the following 
sofia
andriod anything
student.testcases
java support files

if anyone has any answers it is greatly appreciated 
error message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath container: 'Default System Library' in project 'RestaurantGuide-Phase 1'  RestaurantGuide-Phase 1     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    RestaurantGuide-Phase 1     Unknown Java Problem
```

Comment: I had to reinstall java 6 to get mine to work. Also, if you are running the GM edition of Yosemite they released an update to upgrade developers to the retail version the other day. That seemed to help too.

Comment: I have the original/official (app store) version of Yosemite 
where do I download that java update ?
I hope that fixes the issue

Comment: by default java 6 does not come installed with Yosemite which is what is required for the Android SDK.http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted doing this through a fresh copy of Eclipse? It looks like it's simply some conflicts within your build path settings. Also, make sure you've updated to the official release of OS X Yosemite 10.10. If you're interested, I know the beta for 10.10.1 is also out. Make sure you have the JDK installed as well. I would have put this in a comment, however, my reputation isn't high enough to comment yet. If you're still having problems after a fresh download of eclipse, let me know, and we can look into it further.

Comment: Yeah i am still having that same problem after installing it again.
i also got a new JDK and downloaded everything else i needed

Comment: Let's go ahead and uninstall eclipse, Java Runtime, and the JDK. Reboot, and re-install them. With Eclipse saying it's an issue with the build path means either the configuration is wrong, or something is missing (possibly the JDK). Also, is this on a fresh install of Yosemite, or is it after updating? And did it work on Mavericks?

Comment: I can uninstall eclipse, but how do i do that for java runtime, and jdk?
Thats what i though something was missing bc it wouldn't find it (path).
I had mavericks earlier and everything worked fine, i upgraded it from the app store and then it gave me this error

Comment: The JRE should be inside your applications folder. Open finder, and go into there, and drag it into the trash.

Uninstalling the JDK and reinstalling it can be found here
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html)

As for Eclipse, do the same as you did with the JRE.

Comment: Are you sure that the JDK and JRE are both the same major version? (JRE atleast newer than the JDK).

Not sure if this would cause any issues, but maybe check disk permissions and make sure that your files are being accessed alright? Spotlight Search > Disk Utility > Select main partition (Macintosh HD in most cases) > Check/Repair Disk Permissions.

At this point, I'm unsure if its a problem with eclipse, or a problem with OS X

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved Lab-Yelp  Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved CS2114-Support  Unknown Java Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'Default System Library' in project 'CS2114-Support' CS2114-Support  Build path Build Path Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]' in project 'Lab-Yelp' Lab-Yelp  Build path Build Path Problem